# I am getting Errors in wso2esb 4.7.0 how can i avoid this

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am using wso2esb4.7.0 .Before this i have used wso2esb4.6.0 
My issue is in wso2esb4.6.0 we are unable to use multiple http transport But in Wso2esb 4.7.0 we can .its working fine but sometimes its throwing errors 
If i am not wrong this issue because of transport In Esb 4.7.0 version HTTP transport is default but in wso2esb 4.6.0 using HTTP+NIO transport 
It is throwing errors like this and ignoring the connection how can make HTTP+NIO transport in wso2esb4.7.0

```
    2013-08-14 17:10:19,801]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2161
    [2013-08-14 17:10:19,801]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2171
    [2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2162
    [2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2178
    [2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2159
    [2013-08-14 17:10:19,802]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2173
    [2013-08-14 17:10:19,803]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2179
    [2013-08-14 17:10:19,803]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2174
```

how we can avoid this errors in wso2esb4.7.0  otherwise again i will use 4.6.0 is it Bug in 4.7.0 version

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `axis2.xml` file in `ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2` location to enable/disable transports. You will have to comment/uncomment relevant parts under 'Listeners' and 'Senders' sections. Check [this blog post](http://yumani.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-verify-your-esb-is-started-with.html) on enabling NIO transport.

Comment: Thanx for replay i will try and let you know.I knew it But if i am change my transport HTTP to NHTTP i may avoid this issues